# Merging Two Data Frames in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames, the first one representing different daily data of stocks. The second represents the open prices for the same stocks and dates with the same order of dates and name of stocks in the first dataframe.

What I want to do is to combine both of the data frames together so that I have the column of open prices added to the first data frame.

I tried to use pd.concat but it didn't work as you can see in the picture.

I would really appreciate if someone could help, thank you. 
[image: Daily Open Prices]
[image: Fundamental Data]
[image: concat]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As it stands, your question is likely going to be closed because you haven't included any code in the question (code in pictures is very much frowned upon here). Please update your question and happy coding!

Comment: you're going to want to use [pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)